# Change in arrow key behaviour under a GNU screen session

Tags: gnu-screen

I have noticed a weird behavior in `GNU screen` session while using arrow keys. I'm sure it is caused because of a change in setting/configuration. I'm looking here for the root cause of it.

Problem caused: Whenever, I want to switch to view the list of the bash sessions in attached screen using arrow keys, I couldn't. I had to use number keys to move to different bash sessions. Also, while using `VIM`, I couldn't traverse using arrow keys.

Problem solution: I could fixed it using the reset command for `GNU screen` session I had.

However, I'm still not sure what caused the issue.

Comment: check the TERM settings in your shell, and in the screen tabs.  If your terminal is being set to VT-100, or a terminal that doesn't interpret the arrow keys as arrows, that could be the culprit.  Or it may be that screen is trying to set TERM to `screen`, but you don't have the screen termcap installed.  Try running `screen -T xterm` and see if you get the expected behavior.